# generate array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I am trying to generate a 2D n*m array in javascript full of zeros. What is the fastest way of doing that?

I know the simple for loop would be enough to set all the elements to 0, but what I would like to know, why can't I do that with mapping. For example with the underscore lib (or even the native map)

```
_.map(Array(n),function(a){return 0}) // makes {undefined,undefined,...}
```

while

```
_.map([1,2,3,5,6],function(a){return 0}) // makes {0,0,0,0,0}
```

Can anyone explain if I can fill an empty array with a map function and how, or why not?

PS: There is a trivial solution to my problem, I am just asking this cause I would like to learn more, and I cant find a good enough answer on google. Thank you

Comment: You need an object literal {}, not an array ()

Comment: It seems that using `map` on an empty array doesn't work (tested with `(new Array(42)).map(function(){console.log('AAA')})`). BTW, I prefer using loop or (single-dimension) n*m sized array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typical JavaScript `.map()` functions ignore array members that are `undefined`. That's why `Array(n)` doesn't work.

---

You could easily add a method to `Array.prototype` to do a quick fill...

```
Array.prototype.fill = function(n,v) {
    n = n || this.length;
    for( var i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
        this[i] = v === void 0 ? i : v;
    return this;
};
```

then...

```
Array().fill(3); // [0,1,2]

Array().fill(3, 0); // [0,0,0]
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.fill()` is standard in es2015. Also, if you need to use a function to fill values, you can use `new Array(size).fill(null).map(() => Math.random() /* Or whatever */);`

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon: True, you can also do `Array.from(Array(size), () => Math.random())` or in that specific case... `Array.from(Array(size), Math.random)`

Comment: Wow, that's a nice use of `Array.from()`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple trick may be:

```
var myarr = '0000000000'.split('');
```

Another is to make your own map Array extension, to be able to work with `Array(n)`:

```
Array.prototype.mapx = function(callback){
  return this.join(',').split(',').map(callback);
}
//usage
Array(5).mapx(function(){return 0;}); //=> [0,0,0,0,0]
```

I'd think the first one is the fastest, but no time (now) to test it.